# How to show loading progress bar on bottom of UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uiprogressview

I would like to keep the progress bar at bottom part only in `UITextField`. But I don't know how we can keep it for the bottom side.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: what do you want to achieve ..?

Comment: Like mobile no., when i put number on textfield, then progress will increase according to number.After 10 digit number progress complete then it should navigate to next screen.

Comment: You can read here how to customise your textfields [Swiftyninja](https://https://www.swiftyninja.com/customising-text-fields-with-swift-3/)

Comment: @Aayushi I have add answer according your requirement.

Comment: @Kirit Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to do following code for processing textfield with its characters.

**STEP 1** IBOutlet connection of textfield and also delegate connection.

**STEP 2** Take one layer `CALayer`.

```
CALayer *board;
```

**STEP 3** Init layer in ViewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    board = [CALayer layer];
}
```

**STEP 4** textFiled Delegate method. Here I will Apply the logic for Phone number with static, You can Apply your logic according to requirement.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSLog(@"range %lu",(unsigned long)range.location);

    if ([textField.layer.sublayers containsObject:board]) {
        [board removeFromSuperlayer];
    }

    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    board.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    board.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, (textField.frame.size.width / 10.0) * range.location, textField.frame.size.height);
    board.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [textField.layer addSublayer:board];
    return true;
}
```

**Your OUTPUT :**

[image: MY OUTPUT]

Answer (score 1):

You can put `UIProgressView` under your `UITextField`

Answer (score 0):

Make **UITextField With No Border** and add **UIProgressView** bottom of UITextField.

[image: progress view]